# Next.js, попытка зарустить сервер. Ошибка

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, nextjs, next.js, termux

```
~/web-weis $ ls
LICENSE         node_modules       public
README.md       package-lock.json  src
jsconfig.json   package.json       tailwind.config.js
next.config.js  postcss.config.js
~/web-weis $ npm run dev

> web-weis@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.3
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

   Downloading swc package @next/swc-android-arm64...
 ⨯ Failed to download swc package from https://registry.npmjs.org/@next/swc-android-arm64/-/swc-android-arm64-14.0.3.tgz
Error: request failed with status 404
    at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:96:23
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async extractBinary (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:90:9)
    at async downloadNativeNextSwc (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:139:9)
    at async tryLoadNativeWithFallback (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:291:5)
    at async /data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:275:40
Error: request failed with status 404
    at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:96:23
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async extractBinary (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:90:9)
    at async downloadNativeNextSwc (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-swc.js:139:9)
    at async tryLoadNativeWithFallback (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:291:5)
    at async /data/data/com.termux/files/home/web-weis/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:275:40
```

> Исполняю код в приложении: termux.
> : 12 андроид, 64 битное устройство, aarch 64, arm64.

При попытке включить сервер и посмотреть что это за фрукт я столкнулся с подобной ошибкой которая выше описана. Чем можете помочью

Comment: [Failed to load SWC feedback](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30468)